# How to update particular item in listview while on backpress from detail view page?

Tags: android, listview, onbackpressed

How to update particular item in list view while on back press from detail view page?
I'm having custom listview displaying items with like and dislike button, if i click the particular item it will navigate to detail page, in detail page user made any changes it show reflect on listview when user onbackpress in detail page. can anyone give me solution. i tried many method,but am not able to find solution.here is my code

### Latest_Jokes.java

```
public class Latest_Jokes extends Fragment {

public Latest_Jokes() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    this.inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.latest_jokes, container, false);
    //  error_message = (RelativeLayout) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.error_message);


    pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    editor = pref.edit();


    width = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

    extend = (ImageView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.extend);
    listview = (ListView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.list_jokes);
    userId = pref.getString("userId", null);
    nsfwcode = pref.getString("nswKey", null);
    Token = pref.getString("Token", null);
    new LatestTask().execute(nsfwcode, userId);
    return inflatedView;

}

private class LatestTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Global_Url.jokes_url);

        try {

            userId = pref.getString("userId", null);
            nsfwcode = pref.getString("nswKey", null);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("page", String.valueOf(current_page)));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", userId));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nsfw", nsfwcode));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", Token));

            Log.e("userId", userId + nsfwcode);


            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));


            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

            if (inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
            throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        jsonStr = result;
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            JSONObject jsono = null;
            try {
                jsono = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                String error_status = jsono.getString("status");
                Log.e("jsono", String.valueOf(jsono));

                if (error_status.equals("0")) {
                    listview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // error_message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (error_status.equals("403")) {

                    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.commit();
                    Intent edit_page = new Intent(getContext(), Login.class);
                    startActivity(edit_page);
                } else {

                    jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                        jok_id.add(object.getString("jok_id"));
                        jok_desc.add(object.getString("jok_desc"));
                        jok_img.add(object.getString("jok_img"));
                        jok_is_active.add(object.getString("jok_is_active"));
                        jok_nsfw.add(object.getString("jok_nsfw"));
                        jok_total_comments.add(object.getString("jok_total_comments"));
                        jok_total_flags.add(object.getString("jok_total_flags"));
                        jok_total_shares.add(object.getString("jok_total_shares"));
                        jok_created_on.add(object.getString("jok_created_on"));
                        jok_modified_on.add(object.getString("jok_modified_on"));
                        userName.add(object.getString("jok_username"));
                        jokeLike.add(object.getString("likeStatus"));
                        jok_userimg.add(object.getString("jok_userimg"));
                        likeCount.add(object.getString("likeCount"));
                        dislikeCount.add(object.getString("dislikeCount"));
                        popularJoke.add(object.getString("jok_is_popular"));
                        languagename.add(object.getString("language"));


                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        listview.setAdapter(new CustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(), userName, jokeLike, jok_id, jok_desc, jok_img, jok_is_active, jok_nsfw,
                jok_total_comments, jok_total_flags, jok_total_shares, jok_created_on
                , jok_modified_on, jok_userimg, likeCount, dislikeCount, popularJoke, languagename));

    }}}
```

### DetailedViewJokes.java

```
public class DetailedViewJokes extends Activity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
Dialog dialog;
final Context context = this;
String encoded;
JSONArray contacts = null;
String option,jokeingid,Token;
int post;
String path;
private static final String  TAG_DATA = "data";
private static final String TAG_COMMENTS = "comments";

private static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "username";
private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

String detailview_name,detailview_smile,detailview_frown,detailview_comments,detailview_share,
        detailview_jokeimage,detailview_profile,detailview_desc,detailview_time,detailview_jokeid,userId, likeStatus,popularstatus,user_type_id
        , commentClick,lang,like_response;
public static String jokeindex = null;
TextView detail_language,title,frowns,comments,detail_name,detail_smile_count,detail_frown_count,detail_comment_count,detail_share_count,detail_description,detail_time,comment_button,comment_hide;
ImageView detail_joke_image,detail_profile_image;
LinearLayout share,comment_icon,comment_layout,detail_flag_icon,mLinearListView,layout_bottom,layout2;
EditText commit_et;
CheckBox  detail_mark_popular;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private SharedPreferences pref;
Intent i;
String comment,userLikeString,userDislikeString;
File file;
Bitmap bmp;
ScrollView scroll;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.details_view);

    pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    editor = pref.edit();
    userId = pref.getString("userId", null);
    Token = pref.getString("Token",null);
    user_type_id =  pref.getString("typeId", null);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), CustomBaseAdapter.jokeLike+"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    new AsyncHttpTask().execute();
    //ListView lv = getListView();

    i = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = i.getExtras();

    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    detail_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_name);
    detail_smile_count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_smile_count);
    detail_frown_count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_frown_count);
    detail_comment_count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_comment_count);
    detail_share_count = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_share_count);
    detail_time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_time);
    detail_description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_descc);
    comment_button = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.comment_button);
    comment_hide = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.comment_hide);
    scroll = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.detail_scroll);
    detail_language = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detail_language);
    layout_bottom = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_bottom);

    detail_joke_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detail_joke_image);
    detail_profile_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detail_user_profile);
    detail_mark_popular = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.detail_mark_popular);
    final ImageView detail_up = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detail_up);
    final ImageView detail_downe = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.detail_down);

    mLinearListView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.commentlist);
    layout2 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout2);


    commit_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment_tv);

    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    frowns = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.frowns);
    comments = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.comments);


    comment_icon = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.detail_comment_icon);
    comment_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.comment_layout);
    detail_flag_icon = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.detail_flag_icon);

    if(likeStatus.equals("1")){
        detail_up.setImageResource(R.drawable.upvotes);
    }else if(likeStatus.equals("2")) {
        detail_downe.setImageResource(R.drawable.downvotes);
    }
    detail_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            detail_up.setImageResource(R.drawable.upvotes);
            detail_downe.setImageResource(R.drawable.downvotes_gray);
            like_response ="You Upvoted";
            userLikeString = pref.getString("userLike", null); // getting String
            userDislikeString = pref.getString("userDislike", null);

            if(likeStatus.equals("1")){

            }else if(likeStatus.equals("2")){
                detail_smile_count.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(detailview_smile) + 1));
                detail_frown_count.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(detailview_frown) - 1));
                detailview_smile = detail_smile_count.getText().toString();
                detailview_frown = detail_frown_count.getText().toString();
                editor.putString("userLike", String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(userLikeString) + 1));
                editor.putString("userDislike", String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(userDislikeString) - 1));
                editor.commit();
                userLikeString = pref.getString("userLike", null); // getting String
                userDislikeString = pref.getString("userDislike", null);
                TabMenu.userLikeTextView.setText(userLikeString);
                TabMenu.userDislikeTextView.setText(userDislikeString);
            }else {
                detail_smile_count.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(detailview_smile) + 1));
                detailview_smile = detail_smile_count.getText().toString();
                editor.putString("userLike", String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(userLikeString) + 1));
                editor.commit();
                userLikeString = pref.getString("userLike", null); // getting String
                TabMenu.userLikeTextView.setText(userLikeString);
            }


            likeStatus = "1";
            new LikeTask().execute(likeStatus);

        }
    });

    detail_downe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            detail_up.setImageResource(R.drawable.upvotes_gray);
            detail_downe.setImageResource(R.drawable.downvotes);
            like_response ="You Downvoted";
            userLikeString = pref.getString("userLike", null); // getting String
            userDislikeString = pref.getString("userDislike", null);

            if(likeStatus.equals("1")){
                detail_smile_count.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(detailview_smile) - 1));
                detail_frown_count.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(detailview_frown) + 1));
                detailview_smile = detail_smile_count.getText().toString();
                detailview_frown = detail_frown_count.getText().toString();
                editor.putString("userLike", String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(userLikeString) - 1));
                editor.putString("userDislike", String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(userDislikeString) + 1));
                editor.commit();
                userLikeString = pref.getString("userLike", null); // getting String
                userDislikeString = pref.getString("userDislike", null);
                TabMenu.userLikeTextView.setText(userLikeString);
                TabMenu.userDislikeTextView.setText(userDislikeString);
            }else if(likeStatus.equals("2")){

            }else {
                detail_frown_count.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(detailview_frown) + 1));
                detailview_frown = detail_frown_count.getText().toString();
                editor.putString("userDislike", String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(userDislikeString) + 1));
                editor.commit();
                userDislikeString = pref.getString("userDislike", null);
                TabMenu.userDislikeTextView.setText(userDislikeString);
            }
            likeStatus = "2";
            new LikeTask().execute(likeStatus);
        } });
    if(commentClick.equals("1")){
        comment_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }}

public class LikeTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Global_Url.like_url);

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("jid",detailview_jokeid));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", userId));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("status", likeStatus));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", Token));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));


            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();

            if (inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream)
            throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        try {
            JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(result);
            String jarray = jsono.getString("status");


            if(jarray.equals("0")){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  like_response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),like_response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
 }}
```

Comment: Are you able to get the listView (the one you want to update) from DetailedView?